# Azure BLOB Shared Access Signature at the BLOB level, not container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've done a ton of searching and looking at examples but cannot find what I think is possible.  I want to give read access on a blob-by-blob basis, and NOT open the entire container to be readable.  All the examples I found show how to create a full authenticated URL for a blob, which I got working.  What I'm finding is that I can take that SAS key and append that to any other blobs in the same container and they will be readable.

Can I create a SAS key that is only valid for a single BLOB?  If so, an example/link would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly set shared access signature at Blob level. If you're using .Net Storage Client library, do take a look at [`GetSharedAccessSignature`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.getsharedaccesssignature.aspx) function on a blob. I wrote a blog post on Shared Access Signature some time back where you will find some code for creating SAS for blob: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  However, on the page you reference there's a function called "GetSaSForBlob", which is what I think I need.  But no where in the code example is that method called.

Comment: So what you do is 1st call this method on a blob by providing appropriate permission (`SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read` if you want to create a SAS using which your users would be able to download the blob`) and get a SAS URL. Then scroll down to "Download Blobs" section in the post to see how that SAS URL is used.